# Inhabilitar ciertos meses en el arranque datepicker para cualquier año

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, datepicker

Estoy usando datepicker de bootstrap, configurado para viewMode: "años", minViewMode: "meses" y tengo la necesidad de deshabilitar ciertos meses en cualquier año que elija dependiendo de un dato externo.

Por ejemplo en la siguiente imagen debo habilitar los trimestres por lo que debería elegir sólo enero, abril, julio y septiembre, los demás deben ser inhabilitados u ocultos.

[image: datepicker con los meses de inicio de cada trimestre marcados]

Otro ejemplo: si es semestral, debería poder escojer sólo enero y julio como en la imagen, los demás meses deshabilitados o escondidos.

[image: datepicker con enero y julio marcados]

Esto es lo que hice, pero no funciona correctamente. Sólo si le paso el mouse por encima de las casillas las deshabilita, pero aún así las puedo escojer

```js
$('#fechaf').datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            format: 'yyyy/mm',
            viewMode: "years",
            minViewMode: "months"
        }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
            var valid_months = "1,7";
            var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
            $(".month").hover(function () {
                var month = $(this).html(), index = +months.indexOf(month) + 1;
                var index_valid = valid_months.indexOf(index.toString());
                if (index_valid >= 0) {
                    $(this).addClass('available').removeClass('disabled');
                }
                else {
                    $(this).addClass('disabled').removeClass('active').removeClass('available');
                }
            });
        }).data('datepicker')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

consegui hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
$('#fechaf').datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            format: 'yyyy/mm',
            viewMode: "years",
            minViewMode: "months"
        }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
           
            var monthsf = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
            $('.month').show();
            $('.month').each(function () {
                var monthf = $(this).html(), indexf = +monthsf.indexOf(monthf) + 1;
                var index_validf = -1;
                var ss = valid_monthsf.split(",");
                for (var i in ss) {
                    if (ss[i] == indexf.toString()) {
                        index_validf = ss[i];
                        
                    }
                }
                if (index_validf >= 0) {
                    $(this).addClass('available').removeClass('disabled');
                }
                else {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
        });
```

y queda para trimestral por ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]